# Set Filtered TCP Ports via iptables For Linux Device

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, nmap

Here is the configuration :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8888 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 8888 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP  
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

and the results for given configuration on linux device :

```
[root@jibe-eek /ecr]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:8888 state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:8888 state ESTABLISHED
[root@jibe-eek /ecr]#
```

Here is the nmap scan for that device (I scaned just 8800 - 9000 ports for fast response):

```
change@ubuntu ~$ sudo nmap -sS -sU -PN -O -p 8800-9000 192.168.20.196

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-02-01 08:49 EET
Nmap scan report for 192.168.20.196
Host is up (0.0011s latency).
Not shown: 201 open|filtered ports, 200 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8888/tcp closed sun-answerbook
MAC Address: 9C:14:65:10:0F:C3 (Unknown)
Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details
Network Distance: 1 hop

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 9.97 seconds
change@ubuntu ~$
```

As you see my 8888 port is open but i want to make it open | filtered. Is there a way to do that? In the below you will see an ubuntu nmap scan example.

Here is an example of ubuntu computer nmap scan :

```
change@ubuntu ~$ sudo nmap -sS -sU -PN -O -p 8800-9000 192.168.20.251

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-01-31 16:59 EET
Nmap scan report for 192.168.20.251
Host is up (0.000048s latency).
All 402 scanned ports on 192.168.20.251 are closed
Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details
Network Distance: 0 hops

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.75 seconds
change@ubuntu ~$ sudo nmap -sS -sU -PN -O -p 1-9000 192.168.20.251

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-01-31 17:00 EET
Nmap scan report for 192.168.20.251
Host is up (0.000057s latency).
Not shown: 17992 closed ports
PORT     STATE         SERVICE
22/tcp   open          ssh
111/tcp  open          rpcbind
2049/tcp open          nfs
68/udp   open|filtered dhcpc
111/udp  open          rpcbind
601/udp  open|filtered unknown
2049/udp open          nfs
5353/udp open|filtered zeroconf
No exact OS matches for host (If you know what OS is running on it, see http://nmap.org/submit/ ).
TCP/IP fingerprint:
OS:SCAN(V=5.21%D=1/31%OT=22%CT=1%CU=1%PV=Y%DS=0%DC=L%G=Y%TM=5890A68C%P=i686
OS:-pc-linux-gnu)SEQ(SP=108%GCD=1%ISR=10C%TI=Z%CI=I%II=I%TS=8)OPS(O1=M400CS
OS:T11NW4%O2=M400CST11NW4%O3=M400CNNT11NW4%O4=M400CST11NW4%O5=M400CST11NW4%
OS:O6=M400CST11)WIN(W1=8000%W2=8000%W3=8000%W4=8000%W5=8000%W6=8000)ECN(R=Y
OS:%DF=Y%T=40%W=8018%O=M400CNNSNW4%CC=Y%Q=)T1(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%S=O%A=S+%F=AS%R
OS:D=0%Q=)T2(R=N)T3(R=N)T4(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=A%A=Z%F=R%O=%RD=0%Q=)T5(R=Y%
OS:DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)T6(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=A%A=Z%F=R%
OS:O=%RD=0%Q=)T7(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)U1(R=Y%DF=N%T=4
OS:0%IPL=164%UN=0%RIPL=G%RID=G%RIPCK=G%RUCK=G%RUD=G)IE(R=Y%DFI=N%T=40%CD=S)

Network Distance: 0 hops

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 13.04 seconds
change@ubuntu ~$
```

As you see some port STATEs are open|filtered. Can i do filtered tcp ports on my linux device?

You can also see in the image what i want to make more clear :  [IMAGES OF DEVICE AND IPTABLES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odmDH.png)

Comment: Could you please post program output as text, not as images? You can select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content and apply code formatting.

Comment: I changed as you said. Thanks for warning muru.

Comment: You are getting those filtered responses because you have services listening on those ports. Do `sudo netstat -tlpun` to observe. Not sure it will do what you want, but try "REJECT" instead of "ACCEPT" on your input chain.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
_safeNetwork="192.168.0.0/24"

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s $_safeNetwork --dport 8888 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 8888 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

This way it will filter the connections to your machines only from your "safe network" and drop the rest.